# update pathgraphic only

Tags: graphics, c#-3.0

I use the following code to draw line as following

```
        private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e); 
        path = new GraphicsPath(new Point[]{ new Point(10, 10),
                                           new Point(100, 100)  }  ,
           new byte[] {(byte)PathPointType.Start,
                      (byte)PathPointType.Line });
        e.Graphics.DrawPath(Pens.Red, path);
    }
```

I need when click a button to change the path and redraw it only so I use

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        for (int i = 0; i < path.PointCount; i++)
        {

            path.PathPoints[i].X += 100;
            path.PathPoints[i].Y += 100;


        }


         Invalidate();



        //path.

    }
```

the problem no effect happened, and I don't want to refresh the container I draw on it

Answer (score 0):

First, it will not give you any effect since you always create a new path in `OnPaint`. As a result you have the same picture. In order to change it you need at least move your path creation to the constructor or another initialization method

Second, `PathPoint` is an array of `PointF`, `PointF` is a structure, therefore it is immutable and you will not get a new point in array by doing so - `PathPoints[i].X += 10`

Comment: how to draw in the constructor I mean what's the equivalent to e.Graphics

Comment: you don't need to draw in constructor, I was talking about data. Initialize your array of points in constructor, draw only in OnPaint